# Automatic update or sync a table data from Postgresql to Mysql, is it possible without excel import or replication?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, migration

I have two database one is Postgresql and another is Mysql Database in different serve. I copied all the data from Postgresql to Mysql using excel import. From postgresql export all data in excel and then using phpexcel library script those excel data inserted in Mysql.

Now my issue is, in Postgresql for example table_A data is continue updating. I need those data in Mysql table_A also. I thing excel export and import is not best solution. is there any where i can automatic or sync table data postgresql to mysql?

Thanks for your feedback in advance. Have a nice day at work.

Comment: You can try to connect to the MySQL from the Postgres using a [foreign data wrapper](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) and put a trigger on the table to reflect any changes on it on the foreign table. Or maybe it's even possible to do replication via a foreign data wrapper, I'm not sure on this.

Comment: You could create a PHP script that connects to both databases and updates from one to the other. You could then run this as a CRON job every few minutes, or whatever frequency you need.

Comment: The best answer depends on how much replication latency you can live with (real-time? 1 second? 1 hour?) ; should updates be allowed on postgres if mysql server is unreachable and replicated later, or not allowed at all? How many updates per second do you want to replicate?

Comment: @bobflux currently time is not in my concern.